# Can I travel from a Non-EU country to an EU country with a residence permit from another Schengen country?

Tags: visas, schengen, europe, schengen-visas, eu

I am from outside the EU and I am currently in the Netherlands with a temporary Dutch residence permit. I wanna go home to visit my family and I was wondering if I am allowed to use my Dutch residence permit to travel back to Europe from my country to France and then go back to the Netherlands?

PS: I am from Tunisia so usually I need a visa for France

Thank you

Comment: Thanks but I know I can travel within the Schengen area. I was wondering once I leave Europe and want to go back if I can go to France first when I have a Dutch residence permit.

Comment: That’s pretty much what the answer to the duplicate question says :-)

Answer (score 0):

A residence permit or card issued in uniform format ([list](https://ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/sites/homeaffairs/files/e-library/documents/policies/borders-and-visas/schengen/docs/handbook-annex_22.pdf)) from a Schengen state exempts you from any visa requirement for stays of no more than 90 days in any 180-day period. Usually, recently issued residence permit should be in a credit-card format with EU bull symbol on it.

> For intended stays on the territory of the Member States of a duration
>   of no more than 90 days in any 180-day period, which entails
>   considering the 180-day period preceding each day of stay, the entry
>   conditions for third-country nationals shall be the following:
>   ...
>   (b) they are in possession of a valid visa, if required pursuant to
>   Council Regulation (EC) No 539/2001 (25), **except where they hold a
>   valid residence permit or a valid long-stay visa**;
>   ...

Art. 6, [Schengen Borders Code](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=celex%3A32016R0399)

However, a temporary permit issued pending examination of an application for a residence permit or an application for asylum does not qualify as a residence permit.

Comment: Actually, any residence permit has this effect, uniform format or otherwise.